# gradle publish - only selective projects

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a gradle parent project with few sub-projects.
For example - my settings.gradle is like below -

```
rootProject.name = 'myproject-service'
include 'myproject-service-restclient'
include 'myproject-service-core'
include 'myproject-service-server'
```

I have configured gradle maven-publish task in the root project's `build.gradle` and applied it to all sub-projects as I want to publish all the sub-projects.

To publish above projects i am running -
`gradle publish`
and its publishing **all** of the above projects.

So far so good. But the problem I have is - when i do changes to `myproject-service-core`, I only want to publish `myproject-service-core`'s binary(i.e `myproject-service-core.jar`) to maven repo. I am not able to figure out how to publish only selective projects.

I need something like - `gradle publish --project myproject-service-core` <-- how to achive this.

Comment: "You can use task’s fully qualified name to execute a specific task in a specific subproject. For example: `gradle :services:webservice:build` will run the build task of the webservice subproject."

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html#sec:executing_tasks_by_fully_qualified_name

Answer (score 0):

> $ gradle myproject-service-core:publish

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).